# The container view has 0 childs, but when I call view.addView(childView) it crashes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'am trying to add header to the listview (RecylcerView) first time when the data is loaded everything works fine but after refresh when data loads again it say's :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

this is my where I'm getting this error

```
private void prepareHeaderFooter(HeaderFooterViewHolder vh, View view){
    //empty out our FrameLayout and replace with our header
    try {
        vHolder.headerContainer.removeAllViews();
        vHolder.headerContainer.addView(view);
        vHolder.initViews(view);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when I check this vHolder.base views childCount is 0 but addView makes stell error

Comment: Do you have any header added ?

Comment: Please update the method in which you are making call to `prepareHeaderFooter()` and also your XML file if possible

Comment: According your crash message, nothing is wrong in frame view, problem is in the view which you are trying to add in the frame.

Comment: yes, added when app launches first time, but when i'm refreshing this method is calling and i'm getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem, after every time refresh i were setting the adapter to the listview, this is method where I were setting adapter;

```
 public void fillData(final List<MyGarbageModel> data){
    try {
        if (presenter.getAdapter() == null) {
            presenter.initAdapter(data);
            presenter.getAdapter().addHeader(headerView);
            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            listView.setAdapter(presenter.getAdapter());
        } else {
            presenter.notifyDataChanges(data);
        }
        //I moved this line to the first if scope and everything works fine
        //listView.setAdapter(presenter.getAdapter());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with a custom listview in which I was trying to add header and footer view .

I tried this way finally :

```
 mHeaderContainer.removeAllViews();
    if(checkPhoneBuildVersion()){
        removeHeaderView(mHeaderContainer5);
    }


private boolean checkPhoneBuildVersion(){
    return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH;
}
```

Comment: for what is this check? i'm running on marshmollow

Answer (score 0):

The specified child already has a parent.

The View which you add,is already has parent, check it.